# Can custom file types be used in fileimporter?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to be able to select files other than the ones predefined?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fileName = ""
    @State var openFile = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            Text(fileName)
            
            Button(action: {openFile.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Open")
            })
        }
        
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: []) { (res) in

        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to specify general types like .audio for allowedContentTypes, but I would like a specific file extension to be allowed.

I followed the directions on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app), but it didn't work.

I ended up with this in my Info.plist:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.txt</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.company.srt-document</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>srt</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: That's not my problem description. That was showcasing what I've tried. I read through the documentation that I linked and was not able to get it to work using those instructions. Now, whether that is page is actually relevant or not, I am not aware. I'll update my question with the relevant part of my Info.plist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all do you need to change the conforms to type in the Info.plist to

```
public.text
```

Then in your code you need to create an `UTType` object for your file type.

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    let srtType = UTType(exportedAs: "com.company.srt-document", conformingTo: .text)
```

and then use it in the file import call

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [srtType]) { (res) in
    //...
}
```

*I had some issues getting this to work even though everything looked correct but by deleting the project folder under DerivedData so that everything got built/generated from start the next time I did a build in Xcode I got my test app to see and import the .srt files I had created.*

Comment: This answer is amazing. I used this technique to access a different format than .srt (.mts as public.movie, conforming to .movie), have no idea how I would've ever figured this out on my own. Now off to AVFoundation to do some conversions and beat my head against the next wall. One step closer. Thank you, Joakim!